# Looping with helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm reading the helm documentation about how to do some loops for Kubernetes, basically what i want to do is something like [this](https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md).

What i have...

**values.yaml**

```
dnsAliases:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

on **services-external.yaml**

```
{{- if and .Values.var1.var1parent (eq .Values.var2.var2parent "value") }}
{{- range .Values.dnsAliases }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name-{{ . }} ( for creating the name "name-test1/test2 and so on"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: {{ .Values.var3.var3parent }}-{{ .Values.var4.var4parent }}-{{ .}}.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

but im having the error

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: render error in "services-external.yaml": template: templates/services-external.yaml:312:32: executing "services-external.yaml" at <.Values.var3.var3parent>: can't evaluate field Values in type interface {}
```

I tried also with "with" but same error. Is there some way to achieve it by using the "if" with a loop on helm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you have shows that template can't find values for  `<.Values.var3.var3parent>`. Since you're using `range` block, `.` refers to local variables within the loop. You need to refer to global variables. This can be achieved with two approaches:

- Use `$` before a variable you need to invoke (see it with `var3`)
- Define a new variable and save values you need to this variable (see it with `var4`)

Here's a tested template with two approaches from the above:

```
{{- if and .Values.var1.var1parent (eq .Values.var2.var2parent "value") }}
{{- $var4 := .Values.var4 -}}
{{- range .Values.dnsAliases }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name-{{ . }} ( for creating the name "name-test1/test2 and so on"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: {{ $.Values.var3.var3parent }}-{{ $var4.var4parent }}-{{ .}}.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
```

You can read about it more [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

Also there is one more possible solution for this to reset the scope to root and work with loop as usually (but it's more sketchy approach) ([here's a link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1311#issuecomment-625976875))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @moonkotte i managed to make it work using the approach of defining a new variable to save the scope, here the example.

On **values.yaml**

```
    dnsShortNames:
      short1: "short1"
      short2: "short2"
      short3: "short3"
    
    dnsAliases:
      - test1
      - test2
      - test3
```

on **services-external.yaml**

```
    {{- $dns_short_names := .Values.dnsShortNames }} 
      {{- range .Values.dnsAliases }}
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: name-{{ . }}
    spec:
      type: ExternalName
      externalName: {{ $dns_short_names.short1 }}-{{ $dns_short_names.short2 }}-{{ $dns_short_names.short3 }}{{.}}.svc.cluster.local
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 80
      {{- end }}
```

Applying this Kubernetes will create 3 different external services.

```
    short1-short2-short3.test1.svc.cluster.local
    short1-short2-short3.test2.svc.cluster.local
    short1-short2-short3.test3.svc.cluster.local
```

Public thanks to my friend Xavi <3.